# why htmlFor doesn't works in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

htmlFor doesn't works

```
render() {
    return (
        <div style={{ marginTop: '10px' }} />
            <label htmlFor="prueba"> selecciona un archivo</label>
            <input name="prueba" type="file" />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: The `for` attribute (`htmlFor` in JSX) value should be the *id* of the `<input>`. That can be the same as the name, but the attributes are separate.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please [**search**](/search?q=htmlfor) before posting. More on searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: You also made a typo, your first `div` tag should not have a closing `/` at the end of tis definition : `<div style={{ marginTop: '10px' }}>`. This was what the other answer was trying to fix btw @Pointy

Comment: I change the 'name' attribute for 'id' and it still doesn't work

Comment: 'I doesn't work' is not a question. We can not figure out what is going wrong if you do not give any details

Comment: @Treycos the "self-closing" `/>` construction is allowed in HTML 5 but ignored; it's treated exactly the same as `>`.

Comment: While HTML5 will allow that to pass, the compiler will shout all kinds of insults and refuse it.

Comment: If by "compiler" you mean React/JSX, then sure I can believe that. But the browser's HTML parser doesn't care. (It does beg the question of why the OP ignored that.)